# drupal 8 can not use other class in my func

Tags: drupal-8

I wrote

```
use \Drupal\drupal_moodle_integration\Services\CourseService;
```

Then I wrote in my custon form class

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $c = new CourseService;
    dump($c->getCoursesList());
}
```

I got error after submitting

```
ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Drupal\drupal_moodle_integration\Services\CourseService::__construct(), 0 passed in U:\Users\admin\Documents\OpenServer5\OSPanel\domains\D8-bgipp\modules\ex_form\ex_form\src\Form\ExForm.php on line 51 and exactly 3 expected in Drupal\drupal_moodle_integration\Services\CourseService->__construct() (line 46 of modules\contrib\drupal_moodle_integration\src\Services\CourseService.php).
```

How should I wrote to use this class?

I do not understand, in other class this class CourseService called in construct without arguments

```
  /**
   * Construct for Course Controller.
   *
   * @param Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager
   *   The entity type manager.
   * @param Drupal\drupal_moodle_integration\Services\CourseService $courseService
   *   Moodle course service.
   */
  public function __construct(EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager, CourseService $courseService) {
    $this->entityTypeManager = $entity_type_manager;
    $this->courseService = $courseService;
  }
```

Comment: It's not "called" without arguments, it's been passed in as an already defined object. Your constructor "takes" an object of type CourseConstructor, so somewhere it's either injected or set up prior to the use of the object. In your code, you're trying to create a new object so you need to supply the parameters as requested.

Comment: As we told you yesterday on https://drupal.stackexchange.com you need to inject a dependency as it's done in your `Course` controller.

If you share your whole form class I can help you writing it. I need your services.yml too (at least the part declaring `Drupal\drupal_moodle_integration\Services\CourseService`). Please upgrade your question with those elements.

Answer (score 0):

In drupal 8 we never instanciate an object using `new` but using a [dependency injection](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/services-and-dependency-injection/services-and-dependency-injection-in-drupal-8) instead ([example of dependency injection for a form](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/services-and-dependency-injection/dependency-injection-for-a-form)). The dependency is injected in `create()` and the object is instanciated in `construct()`, then you can use it wherever you want in the class.

In your form class you need something like :

```
namespace Drupal\drupal_moodle_integration\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\drupal_moodle_integration\Services\CourseService;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class YourClassForm extends FormBase {

  /**
   * Construct for YourClassForm.
   *
   * @param Drupal\drupal_moodle_integration\Services\CourseService $courseService
   *   Moodle course service.
   */
  public function __construct(CourseService $courseService) {
    $this->courseService = $courseService;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    // 'the.name.of.your.courseservice' comes from your drupal_moodle_integration.services.yml.
    return new static(
      $container->get('the.name.of.your.courseservice')
    );
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'your_form_id';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // Build your form here.
    
    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm() {
    // You need devel module to use kint() it's way better than var_dump().
    kint($this->courseService->getCoursesList()); die;
  }

}
```